# Hessian of second-order function of a matrix -- trace(A X^T B X C)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-calculus

How do I find the Hessian (second-derivative) of $f(X) = tr(A X^T B X C)$?

Using differential notation, this has the following first differential:

$d tr(A X^T B X C) = tr((CAX^TB + A^T C^T X^T B^T) dX) $.

This straightforwardly leads to the first derivative $(CAX^TB + A^T C^T X^T B^T)^T = B^T X A^TC^T + BXCA$.

If I've done my algebra correctly, the second differential is

$ d^2 tr(A X^T B X C) = tr(CAdX^T B dX + A^TC^TdX^T B^T dX)$.

How do I obtain the Hessian from this? I believe I need to somehow put this into the form $vec(dX)^T H vec(dX)$, from which I can conclude that the Hessian is $H$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\vc#1{\op{vec}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
$Your gradient calculation is indeed correct. To find the Hessian...

First flatten $X$ and the gradient matrix into vectors
$$\eqalign{
x &= \vc{X} \\
G &= B^TXA^TC^T + BXCA \\
g &= \vc{G} \\&= \LR{CA\otimes B^T}x + \LR{A^TC^T\otimes B}x \\
}$$
Then calculate the gradient of the gradient (i.e. the Hessian)
$$\eqalign{
dg &= \LR{CA\otimes B^T}dx + \LR{A^TC^T\otimes B}dx \\
\grad{g}{x}
 &= \LR{CA\otimes B^T} + \LR{A^TC^T\otimes B}
\;\equiv\; Hessian \\
}$$